# Numpy array filled with random numbers so that you only change the value by one along the x/y axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I know how to create a numpy array filled with random numbers, for instance, this : `np.random.randint(0, 100, (5, 5))`.

But how do you create a numpy array filled with random numbers so that the difference between two adjacent cells is 1 or less ?

Thanks

Comment: _"you only have a change of one around each cell"_ Pardon? Do you mean that the difference between two adjacent cells is 1 or less ?

Comment: Exactly, I meant this. Updating post ...

Comment: Don't think you can with np.random or similar. Create the array with a for-loop instead and keep track of current value for each one created, with a 1/3 chance of incrementing, decrementing or staying the same.

Comment: 1D array sounds easy, but what about 2D cells ? this becomes very tricky.

Comment: I was wondering if there exists a _list comprehension_-like feature on numpy arrays to avoid nested loops ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every row can differ by 1. So generate an array of differences:

```
In [83]: H, W = 5, 5

In [84]: np.random.randint(-1, 2, size=(H,1))
Out[84]: 
array([[ 1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [ 0]])
```

Now find the cumulative sums:

```
In [85]: np.add.accumulate([[ 1], [-1], [-1], [-1], [ 0]])
Out[85]: 
array([[ 1],
       [ 0],
       [-1],
       [-2],
       [-2]])
```

Similarly, every column can differ by 1. So again generate an array of differences,
and find the cumulative sums:

```
In [86]: np.add.accumulate(np.random.randint(-1, 2, size=(1,W)), axis=1)
Out[86]: array([[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]])
```

Now add these two cumulative sums together. Broadcasting creates a 2D array:

```
import numpy as np

H, W = 5, 5
x = np.add.accumulate(np.random.randint(-1, 2, size=(H,1)), axis=0)
y = np.add.accumulate(np.random.randint(-1, 2, size=(1,W)), axis=1)
out = x + y
print(out)
```

prints a random array such as

```
[[ 1  0 -1  0 -1]
 [ 2  1  0  1  0]
 [ 3  2  1  2  1]
 [ 3  2  1  2  1]
 [ 2  1  0  1  0]]
```

You can add constants to this array to generate other random arrays with the same property.

Comment: An efficient solution to my question.